# Programmatically adding root view to view controller does not position correctly

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to add the root view and subviews to a viewcontroller programmatically, but the view is not filling to screen as expected:

```
override func loadView() {
        self.view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        let alertView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CHRApptTakenAlertView", owner: self, options: nil)![0] as! CHRApptTakenAlertView

        self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        alertView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.view.addSubview(alertView)
        self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: alertView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: alertView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        alertView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: alertView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, multiplier: 1, constant: 350))
        alertView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: alertView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, multiplier: 1, constant: 250))

        alertView.closeBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.closeBtnTouch), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    }
```

Comment: You should not be setting `self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`.

Comment: @Sethmr I cannot add the subview after the constraints because the hierarchy must be there before adding constraints. However, removing the two translates lines and adding self.view.layoutIfNeeded() at the end of my loadView() method worked. Add as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the line self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false, and call self.view.layoutIfNeeded() after the adding the constraints.

Comment: Please remove the part stating "Try adding the subview after adding the constraints" as that causes an error because the view hierarchy is not in place for the constraints to be added, and I will accept.